# Finding $(a,b,c)$ such that $8^k=\sqrt{c^2+2ab}+2ab$ holds for integer $a,b$ and $c$ not necessary integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $2^{3k+1} +1$ is divisible by $2a+1$ if and only if there is a right triangle $(a,b,c)$ such that $8^k=\sqrt{c^2+2ab}+2ab$ where $a,b$ are integers and $c$ is any real number.

Example: $k=3$:
$$
(a,b,c)=(12,20,\sqrt{544}), (20,12,\sqrt{544}), (2,102,\sqrt{10408}), (102,2,\sqrt{10408})
$$

Question: Is there anyway to find solutions for $(a,b,c)$ given any $k$?

Comment: Does a right triangle $(a,b,c)$ mean $a^2+b^2=c^2$??

Comment: If so the equation can be simplified to $8^k=a+b+2ab$.

Comment: not necessarily have an odd factor. in fact when k=1 or k=5 no solutions exist

Comment: $2^{3k+1}+1$ definitely has an odd factor, so find a possible $a$ and see wether $\frac{8^k-a}{1+2a}$ is an integer, then $(a,b,c)$ where $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the triple You are searching for.

Comment: yes it is actually reducible to a+b+2ab. Just pointing out the connection to right triangles

Comment: @PeterMelech In fact $2^{3k+1}+1$ has ONLY odd factors

Comment: For $k=1$ the only possible choice for $a$ is 8 and then it follows by $8=8+b+16b$ that $b=0$. as i said one just has to check whether $\frac{8^k-a}{2a+1}$ is a positive integer

Comment: I definitely agree that there can ONLY be odd factors however I am referring to non trivial factors. In fact when k=1,5 no such non trivial factors exist.